# Java - like Apex for SOBJECTS

Tags: apex, java, database

Sorry, I don't know if this is a proper context to make this question, but I don't know where to make this question.

I write here because I immagine that a lot for today apex programmers has been java programmers.

I appreciate the feature of the SObjcet Class, where I can use methods as get/put for the fields of a SObject.

For SOBJECTS I can do things like:

```
Account acc = new account();
Acc.put('name',xxx);
```

The peculiarity is not to use a put method, but the aspect that the method is scalable as the database change, if i add a field, the put method works and is adapted to manage also the new fields. Looks like the method changes automatically with the database. 
I would reproduce a similar approach in java for a Database like MySQL o similar, the question is for a general OOP language and its interaction with a database.

Can you please suggest me any pattern or approach to reproduce similar behaviour?

Comment: This is not on topic here, but what you want, I think, is to use a HashMap.  However, this sounds like a pretty bad idea.  You should consider looking into ORM frameworks like Hibernate.

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman Yes i know that is not on topic, but i didn't know how to make the question out of the community, where the others don't know Salesforce and its peculiarities. Thanks for your suggestion, I will to take a look on the framework. 
I don't understand why you are saying that is not a good idea. The SObject class simplify the life to me, and all the code is transparent to the changes of the database... but maybe I'm just newbie to java :)

Answer (score 1):

I also think this is off-topic, and could be moved to the general StackOverflow. However, have you tried using reflection? The reflection library in Java allows you to reference methods/properties by their names contained in a string.

A quick googling shows this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14374878/using-reflection-to-set-an-object-property